# Javascript animation does not behave in intended way

Tags: javascript

I want create a simple animation where length of a rectangle changes smoothly to half its value when 'mouseover' event occurs and doubles up again when 'mouseout' event occurs. 
the following code works if mouse is moved slowly but doesn't if mouse is moved rapidly. The rectangle just gets stuck if mouse is moved rapidly. Please suggest how to overcome this.

```html
<body>
    <svg id="svg" width="600" height="100">
        <rect id="myrect" width="600" height="100" fill="green">
     </svg>
     <script>
        svg = document.getElementById("svg");
        var w = 600;
        var step = 10;
        
        svg.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){ 
            function anim ()    {
                w -= step;
                if( w >= 300)    {
                    myrect = document.getElementById("myrect");
                    myrect.setAttribute("width", w);
                    requestAnimationFrame(anim);            
                }
            }
            anim();
        });
        
        svg.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){ 
            function anim ()    {
                w += step;
                if( w <= 600)    {
                    myrect = document.getElementById("myrect");
                    myrect.setAttribute("width", w);
                    requestAnimationFrame(anim);            
                }
            }
            anim();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Today, please do not use JavaScript for this kind of animation.
CSS Transitions are made for this - and they show way better performace as most browser can calculate them faster on graphic card rather than CPU.

For more info see [W3C School on CSS Transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

So an improved and lot shorter version of your example would look like

```css
#myrect {
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}
#myrect:hover {
  transform: scale(0.5, 1.0);
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="600" height="100">
  <rect id="myrect" width="600" height="100" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

Note: It seems you can not animate 'width' property for SVGs by simple CSS like done before. For easy handling, you can use translate-property and scale it to 50% of width instead.

(Ok, according to [SVG Standard - Section Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/attindex.html) 'width' can be animated with the more compelx SVG-animation logic, but CSS looks quiet easier and this knowledge can be applied to HTML elements as well :-)  )

Answer (score 0):

Short explanation of the below code:

Animation process unified in a single function that can work in two direction dependent on the `direction` parameter value. Mouse events just change the animation direction. Variable `animActive` prevent from double call of `requestAnimationFrame` and makes direction changes smooth.

```html
<body>
    <svg id="svg" width="600" height="100">
        <rect id="myrect" width="600" height="100" fill="green">
     </svg>
     <script>
        svg = document.getElementById("svg");
        var w = 600;
        var step = 10;
        var direction;
        var animActive = false;
        
        svg.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){ 
            direction = true;
            if (!animActive)
              requestAnimationFrame(anim);
        });
        
        svg.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){ 
            direction = false;
            if (!animActive)
              requestAnimationFrame(anim);
        });
       
       function anim(){
         if (direction){
            if( w > 300){
                animActive = true;
                w -= step;
                myrect = document.getElementById("myrect");
                myrect.setAttribute("width", w);
                requestAnimationFrame(anim);
            }
            else
                animActive = false;
         }
         else{
            if( w < 600){
                animActive = true;
                w += step;
                myrect = document.getElementById("myrect");
                myrect.setAttribute("width", w);
                requestAnimationFrame(anim);            
            }
           else
               animActive = false;
         }
       }
    </script>
</body>
```